# Is it possible to keep record separator in awk?

Tags: linux, command-line, osx

I'd like to separate record by first word (eg DEBUG or INFO)
and keep RS.

but execute program, awk removes RS.

How to keep it?

log.txt is

```
DEBUG:[2018-04-09 13:00:01]
=========================
START LOG 
:
:
END LOG 
===========================

DEBUG:[2018-04-09 13:00:02]
 INFO:[2018-04-09 13:00:03]
DEBUG:[2018-04-09 13:00:04]
=========================
START LOG 
:
:
END LOG 
===========================
```

my trying program is

```
$gawk 'BEGIN{RS="(DEBUG|INFO)"; FS="\n"}{print RS$0}' log.txt
```

but it shows

```
(DEBUG|INFO):[2018-04-09 13:00:01]
=========================
START LOG 
:
:
END LOG 
===========================

(DEBUG|INFO):[2018-04-09 13:00:02]
(DEBUG|INFO):[2018-04-09 13:00:03]
(DEBUG|INFO):[2018-04-09 13:00:04]
=========================
START LOG 
:
:
END LOG 
===========================
```

Comment: What output you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use RT

```
 gawk 'BEGIN{RS="(DEBUG|INFO)"; FS="\n"}{printf "%s%s", $0, RT}' log.txt
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that this is a GNU extension to `awk` not available in BSD `awk` nor in `mawk`.